# Rails: Generar tabla en base a datos que contienen fechas

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en RoR para llevar el seguimiento de servicios de mantenimiento que se realizan en diversas máquinas.

Para intentar simplificar un poco, digamos que tenemos dos modelos, por un lado máquinas y por otro servicios, de modo que servicio `belongs_to` maquina y maquina `has_many` servicios. Estos servicios se definen en base a la fecha en que deben realizarse, la máquina en que se llevan a cabo y el status (por hacer, no OK etc). Mi idea es, como pantalla principal, mostrar un resumen de servicios que deben realizarse, como una tabla de este tipo, donde en las cabecera de la tabla se muestren los meses y en cada "celda" se indique el día del mes que un determinado servicio debe llevarse a cabo para una máquina determinada. Sería algo así:

[image: ejemplo tabla]

La máquina A tiene un servicio programado el día 25 de enero, la B el 3 de marzo y así sucesivamente. ¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacer esto correctamente?.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun entiendo, en tu base de datos tienes algo como lo siguiente:

```
Table Name: Services
machine | date_service(type date)
   A    |   23/01/2017
   B    |   03/03/2017
   C    |   25/02/2017
   B    |   14/07/2017
```

En el controlador deberias tener el metodo show asi:

```
def show
  @services_a = Service.where(:machine => "A").reorder(:date_service)
  @services_b = Service.where(:machine => "B").reorder(:date_service)
  @services_c = Service.where(:machine => "C").reorder(:date_service)
  ...
end
```

y en la vista:

```
<h1>Listing Services</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Maquina</th>
    <th>Enero</th>
    <th>Febrero</th>
    <th>Marzo</th>
    <th>Abril</th>
    ...
  </tr>
```

#Un ciclo de estos por cada maquina que tengas

```
<% @services_a.each do |service| %>
    <% if service.date_service.strftime("%m") == "01" %>
      <tr><td><%= service.date_service %></td>
    <% else %>
      <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <% end %>
    <% if service.date_service.strftime("%m") == "02" %>
      <td><%= service.date_service %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <% end %>
    <% if service.date_service.strftime("%m") == "03" %>
      <td><%= service.date_service %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <% end %>
    <% if service.date_service.strftime("%m") == "04" %>
      <td><%= service.date_service %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <% end %>
    ...
    <% if service.date_service.strftime("%m") == "04" %>
      <td><%= service.date_service %></td></tr>
    <% else %>
      <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<% @services_b.each do |service| %>
    <% if service.date_service.strftime("%m") == "01" %>
      <tr><td><%= service.date_service %></td>
    <% else %>
      <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <% end %>
    <% if service.date_service.strftime("%m") == "02" %>
      <td><%= service.date_service %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <% end %>
    <% if service.date_service.strftime("%m") == "03" %>
      <td><%= service.date_service %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <% end %>
    <% if service.date_service.strftime("%m") == "04" %>
      <td><%= service.date_service %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <% end %>
    ...
    <% if service.date_service.strftime("%m") == "04" %>
      <td><%= service.date_service %></td></tr>
    <% else %>
      <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

</table>
```

Aunque al codigo le falta opotimizacion me parece que funciona, y si falla pues esa es la idea.

Espero de verdad te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu pregunta, que quieres decir con correctamente? Si  la interfaz de usuario que propones está bien?, Si necestias ayuda con como hacerlo en RoR?...

La interfaz de usuario justamente va a depender de tus usuario...es por ello que debes preguntarles a los usuarios.

Comment: Perdon por no ser más explicito, lo que quiero es conseguir ayuda acerca de como hacer exactamente lo que explico en el post inicial, con RoR o con alguna tecnología de front-end tipo jQuery(si puede hacerse solo con RoR/HTML mejor), generar una tabla en base a las fechas en que los servicios deben ser realizados tal como indico.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría un método en la clase Maquina que dado un mes diga cuales servicios estan para ese mes....

```
class Maquina
    def servicios_por_mes(mes, anho)

        proximo_mes = (mes == 12) ? 1 : mes+1
        proximo_anho = (mes == 12) ? anho+1 : anho

        Servicios.where(maquina_id: maquina_id)
            .where(["fecha_servicio >= ?", "#{anho}-#{mes}-01"])
            .where(["fecha_servicio < ?", "#{proximo_anho}-#{proximo_mes}-01"])
            .count
    end
end
```

Luego uso eso en la vista....y se hacen dos ciclos uno por maquina y dentro uno por mes.....